# What's a good way to find recreational mineral prospecting locations in the Pacific Northwest (US) area?

Tags: usa, activities

I'd like to find some destinations in the Pacific Northwest (US) for panning or gathering precious metals or gems, preferably without requiring non-trivial effort to gain access to.  This is meant as a recreational thing with a small group of people.

Comment: for self-panning or as part of a tour/company/tourist spot?

Comment: With others, probably not an extended trip.

Comment: but do you just want to say, go down to a river with friends, or are you looking for a company with tools etc to take you out to a place?

Comment: By company do you mean a literal company or just being in the company of hobbyists or something?

Comment: Well, *I* meant literal company, but you're the one asking the question :)

Comment: We're not objectively seeking a profit or anything like that. It would be neat to go to something like an actual (decommissioned?) mining location, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not from around your area, but prospecting has always been an interest of mine.

[This Geology.com article](http://geology.com/usgs/gold-prospecting/) looks at the general information relating to prospecting in the US, a link from that article [here](http://geology.com/articles/gold-prospecting-tools/) provides more detail.

[This article from Nature of the NorthWest](http://www.naturenw.org/rock-gold.htm) has many links pertaining to the rules, regulations and locations of the gold-panning areas in the Pacific Northwest.

I hope this helps.